# What to do if a conference rebuttal is closed before the specified deadline?

Tags: peer-review, conference, deadlines

My paper was submitted to a conference, and they sent me a rebuttal email specifying the deadline in UTC-12 time zone.

However, when I prepared my rebuttal and tried to submit it into the system, I found that the system was closed. The time was over in my time zone but more than 12 hours were still remaining in UTC-12 time zone.

<strike>Although my paper seemed to be accepted(maybe somewhat marginally), yet</strike> I did not want to demonstrate a naive attitude.

What is the best thing to do in such a situation?

Comment: Wait and see if they fix it on their own.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's always a person, and they're usually reasonable. Just contact the conference chair or program committee chair and ask them to let you know how to send in your rebuttal.

In short, *talk to people*.

Comment: Yep, it worked. The link was opened after my email, and I was able to submit my rebuttal into the system 10 hours before the specified deadline.